# WPF - How can I auto-resize DataGrid column to fit contents

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid, mvvm-light

I have a WPF DataGrid that display some data. Now I want to set auto-resize for some specific columns, not all. Here is my current behavior of DataGrid:

[image]

[image]

This is my expectation (column width should fit its content):

[image]

**XAML**

```
...
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ShippingNumber}" Header="出荷No." ElementStyle="{DynamicResource TextAlignCenter}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding DivisionDisplay}" Header="区分" ElementStyle="{DynamicResource TextAlignCenter}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ShippingDestinationCode}" Header="出荷先コード" ElementStyle="{DynamicResource TextAlignCenter}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
<DataGridTextColumn Width="Auto" Binding="{Binding ShippingDestinationNameDisplay}" Header="出荷先名" ElementStyle="{DynamicResource TextAlignCenter}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
<DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding IsCompletedStockOutcomming}" Header="出庫済み" IsReadOnly="True">
    <DataGridCheckBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
         <Style TargetType="CheckBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type CheckBox}}">
              <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
              <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
              <Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="False"/>
              <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
         </Style>
     </DataGridCheckBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
</DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
```

My project is applying MVVM light pattern so it does not allow to put any code in code-behind, just in ViewModel.
I also set `With="Auto"` but still no use. Can anyone help me to make it works? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried setting `MinWidth` and `MaxWidth`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DataGridLengthUnitType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridlengthunittype(v=vs.110).aspx) SizeToCells enumerator option due to which column width is calculated based on the contents of the cells.

Comment: I tried to add one more property in ViewModel named `CustomWidth` then I set `DataGridLength.SizeToCells` into it. In the xaml file, I bind the column width with this prop like this: `<DataGridTextColumn Width="{Binding DataContext.CustomWidth, ElementName=Page}"...>` but it still no work. If I bind this prop to the Text prop of the TextBlock control I can see the value is `SizeToCells`. So what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Someone said that `DataGridTextColumn` do not derive from FrameworkElement, it is derived from DependencyObject. So it's impossible to bind the property using XAML with `ElementName`. Is it right?  If it's right. what should I do next?

Comment: @QuanNguyen that's right, you need to use a proxy technique. You can search more on that. This answer is correct but your scenario is a bit different when Binding is involved. If you cannot find what the so-called proxy technique (someone calls it hack) in Binding in XAML is, I'll try adding some example as an answer.

Comment: I tried this [post] (http://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/devin_rader/archive/2011/04/29/binding-to-properties-of-non-frameworkelements.aspx) but it seems the author gave shorten code so I could not how to apply this technique in my scenario. So if you can, please help me to give a better example.

Comment: Maybe this would work with the DataGridLengthConverter class?